# ASPNetUserRoles: Edit and DeleteConfirmed methods works unproperly

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I want to manage ASPNetUserRoles table in ASP.net core MVC 6.0 CRUD operations. For this purpose I create Controller, but I faced with strange problem: Edit and DeleteConfirmed methods works unproperly. If I edited fields and pressed button "Save" and nothing happened. In Delete method I pressed "Delete" button, and receive http 405, 500. The row with UserId and RoleId had not been Deleted.
Here is the part of my Controller:

```
using ACC.Areas.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ACC.Areas.Admin.Models.ViewModels;
using ClosedXML.Excel;

namespace ACC.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class AdminAController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;
        private bool UserRoleExists(string userId, string roleId)
        {
            return _context.ApplicationUserRoles.Any(ur => ur.UserId == userId && ur.RoleId == roleId);
        }
        public AdminAController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager, AppDbContext context)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _context = context;
        }

        .....

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            // Find the ApplicationUserRole by the provided userId
            var userRole = await _context.ApplicationUserRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(ur => ur.UserId == id);
            if (userRole == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            // Map the ApplicationUserRole to the view model
            var viewModel = new AdminAViewModel
            {
                UserId = userRole.UserId,
                RoleId = userRole.RoleId
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, AdminAViewModel model)
        {
            if (id != model.UserId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Find the user role by the provided userId
                    var userRole = await _context.ApplicationUserRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(ur => ur.UserId == id);

                    if (userRole == null)
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }

                    // Check if a user role with the specified userId and roleId already exists
                    var existingUserRole = await _context.ApplicationUserRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(ur =>
                        ur.UserId != id && ur.RoleId == model.RoleId);

                    if (existingUserRole != null)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "User with the specified role already exists.");
                        return View(model);
                    }

                    // Update the user role properties
                    userRole.UserId = model.UserId;
                    userRole.RoleId = model.RoleId;

                    _context.ApplicationUserRoles.Update(userRole);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!UserRoleExists(model.UserId, model.RoleId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminA");
            }

            return View(model);
        }



        [HttpGet]
        [Route("AdminA/Delete/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
        {
            // Find the user role by the provided ID
            var userRole = await _context.ApplicationUserRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(ur => ur.UserId == id);

            if (userRole == null)
            {
                // User role not found, handle accordingly (e.g., return an error view)
                return NotFound();
            }

            // Create a view model for displaying the user role details
            var adminAViewModel = new AdminAViewModel
            {
                UserId = userRole.UserId,
                RoleId = userRole.RoleId
            };

            return View(adminAViewModel);
        }

        // DeleteConfirm action (POST)
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("AdminA/DeleteConfirm/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirm(string id)
        {
            // Find the user role by the provided ID
            var userRole = await _context.ApplicationUserRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(ur => ur.UserId == id);

            if (userRole == null)
            {
                // User role not found, handle accordingly (e.g., return an error view)
                return NotFound();
            }

            // Remove the user role from the context
            _context.ApplicationUserRoles.Remove(userRole);

            // Save the changes to the database
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            // Redirect to the index action or any other desired action
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit.cshtml:

```
@model ACC.Areas.Admin.Models.ViewModels.AdminAViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Application ASPNetUserRoles";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Edit User Role</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
            <h2>Edit Role</h2>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="UserId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label">User ID:</label>
                <input asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RoleId" class="control-label">Role ID:</label>
                <input asp-for="RoleId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="RoleId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

Delete.cshtml:

```
@model ACC.Areas.Admin.Models.ViewModels.AdminAViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Application ASPNetUserRoles";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Delete ASPNetUserRole</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="DeleteConfirmed" method="post">
            <h2>Confirm Deletion?</h2>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userId">User ID:</label>
                <input type="text" id="userId" class="form-control" value="@Model.UserId" readonly />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="roleId">Role ID:</label>
                <input type="text" id="roleId" class="form-control" value="@Model.RoleId" readonly />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete this user role?</p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

I missed in the code something or there should be some additional routing added to Program.cs file? I use standard routing in Controller

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: Have you debug your code when you submit the form? In your Edit post method, you receive `string id, AdminAViewModel model` as the parameter, But I don't find any input tag whose  name is `id`, Can you receive the value of `id` in the backend? And there are two `<input asp-for="UserId" />` in your edit view, The form will only submit the value of the first input.

Comment: I fixed delete method and it works. For the Edit method still have problem. The Debug "Validation errors for 'Role':
- The Role field is required.
Validation errors for 'User':
- The User field is required.
Validation errors for 'UserRoles':
- The UserRoles field is required."

Comment: In your edit View, I just find `RoleId` and `UserId` field.

Comment: Yes, as I want to "Edit" them: RoleId and UserId (they are property of ASPNetUserRoles table)

Comment: If you wanna change the relationship between user and role, why let user input `userId` and `roleId`, In my opinion, you can put all the roles into a dropdown list, Then if user want to change a role, He can just select one in this dropdown list, In backend, i prefer to use `RemoveFromRoleAsync(TUser, String)` and `AddToRoleAsync(TUser, String)` in userManager to change the role instead of manipulating ApplicationUserRoles directly.